# Why does "std:;" compile, and what does it mean?

Tags: c++

I recently found a typo in my project which looked like this:

```
std: cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
```

It was compiling fine, although I noticed that I had a `using std::cout` directive in the include chain that was required to prevent a syntax error from `cout` being out of scope. I wrote a test program to see what was going on, and it turns out that `std:;` is a perfectly valid line of c++. What is `std:` doing, and why doesn't it cause syntax errors when combined with the call to `cout`?

Comment: Looks like a goto label to me. I.e. you could now add `goto std;` to your function and it would jump to that line.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: This is called a label.  It is what goto and switch statements use.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! For whatever reason, searching for "std:;" doesn't come up with the prior questions.